# Inserting Values from dropDownList to SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

So i am creating this .NET form that gets values in different forms and adds tham to a SQL local database. As far i have figured out how to get and insert values from texBox, from radio button but now i am not figuring out how to insert into the DB values from DropDownList. Below i am showing some of my code. hope u will help me out. :))

```
<td class="auto-style1">
                               <label for="TextBox5">Mosha:</label>

                           </td>
                           <td class="auto-style1">
                               <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="RadDropDownList1" runat="server" SelectedText="  ">
                                   <Items>
                                       <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Selected="True" Text=" " />
                                           <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="30-35 vjec" />
                                       <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="35-40 vjec" />
                                       <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="40-45 vjec" />
                                       <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="40 &lt;  vjec" />

                                   </Items>

                               </telerik:RadDropDownList>

                           </td></tr

                    <tr></tr><td class="auto-style1"><label for="TextBox3">Departamenti:</label> 

                             </td><td class="auto-style1">
                                 <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="SelectDepartament" DefaultMessage="Select a product" runat="server" SelectedText="Departamenti i Risqeve">
                                     <Items>
                                         <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Selected="True" Text=" " />
                                         <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="Departamenti i Menaxhimit" />
                                         <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="Departamenti i IT" />
                                         <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="DropDownListItem4" />
                                         <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="DropDownListItem5" />
                                         <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="DropDownListItem6" />


                                     </Items></telerik:RadDropDownList>

                                  </td>
                       <tr>
                           <td class="auto-style1">
                                         <label for="TextBox6">Te drejtat ne Internet:</label>

                           </td>
                           <td class="auto-style1">
                               <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="RadDropDownList2" DefaultMessage=" " runat="server">
                                   <Items>
                                       <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="Kategoria A" />
                                       <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="Kategoria B" />
                                       <telerik:DropDownListItem runat="server" Text="Kategoria C" />


                                   </Items>

                               </telerik:RadDropDownList>

                           </td>

 protected void Save2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try{
               SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Rights"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            string insert = "insert into Rights(Name,Mbiemri,Gjinia,Departamenti,Mosha,IntRights,Transferat, Depozite,Raporte) values (@Name,@Mbiemri,@Gjinia,@Departamenti,@Mosha,@IntRights,@Transferta,@Depozite,@Raporte)";
            SqlCommand cnd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);

            cnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text);
            cnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mbiemri", TextBox2.Text);
            cnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gjinia", RadioButtonList1.Text);
            cnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Departamenti", TextBox2.Text);
            cnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mosha", TextBox2.Text);
            cnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IntRights", TextBox2.Text);
            cnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transferta", TransfertaBtn.Text);
            cnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Depozite", DepoziteBtn.Text);
            cnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Raporte", TextBox2.Text);
            cnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("Delete.aspx");
            con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex);
        }


}
```

Comment: What errors are you experiencing? Any exceptions being thrown?

Comment: First of all the code i already have leads me to this error "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Detyre.Home.Save2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)"    And the second thing is that i have not yet written how the items will be inserted in the DB from the dropDownLists i have in my form

Comment: In the actual HTML, where you are using some Telerik dropdowns, you do not have any elements called "TextBox1", "TextBox2" etc. So if they are not declared somewhere else, they are clearly null.

Comment: If they are actually declared somewhere else, you should be able to debug your way through your code, and see what property that is null.  My guess is:
-The "Rights" connection string is not declared in the config file.
-... or one of the elements you are trying to get the values from, ie. ".Text", are not declared.

Comment: Yes i do not have element TextBox1 and two in the shown code here because the real question was about how to add this elements that are in the DropDownList in my SQL BD.

Comment: Aha, then you should set a breakpoint in your code, to debug it, and see what property that is null.